# App crashes silent: try catch finally does not work

Tags: android, crash, try-catch-finally

I have a small app where I play with activating an activity by code. There I have the strange problem that my app dies after enabling a second activity.

Here is my settings activity:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "enableing activity...");

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, Lancher.class);
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
                             PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, 0);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Got some trouble:", e);
    } finally {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "reached finally block");
    }

    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "wohoo activity is enabled");
// ...
```

And here are some lines of my logcat (I removed unrelated output):

> I/ActivityManager(1384): **Starting activity**: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=**com.example.test/.Settings** } from pid 6566
>   ...
>   E/Settings(6592): **enableing activity...**
>   I/PackageManager(1384):  **setEnabledSetting**(), pkgName=**com.example.test**, clsName=**com.example.test.Lancher**, state=1, flag=0, pid=6592, uid=10203
>   ...
>   D/WindowManagerImpl(1384): finishRemoveViewLocked, mViews[1]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4054d318
>   D/Process(1384): killProcess, pid=6592
>   I/ActivityManager(1384): Force stopping package **com.example.test** uid=10203
>   I/RegisterService(6601): android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED package:**com.example.test**

And my manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Lancher"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Do you have any idea why my app crashes without any output from the finally block?

Comment: If you surrond all code with try catch it doesnt enter finally block too?

Comment: Yep so it is and this confuses me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works when you change flag from 0 to 1 or `PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP`

```
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
                              PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                              PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Maybe this is an android issue or misunderstanding android docs.

Do you need really need flag == 0?

Comment: I read somewhere that `DONT_KILL_APP` should not be used, but I don't know the reason.

Comment: DONT_KILL_APP sometimes still kill app.